# How to apply round robin on remaining partitions in kafka if one is restricted

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have restricted one partition of a topic to be used for a particular service (So all requests will arrive here for service X). for any other service request will arrive on remaining N partitions.

In java i implemented it via `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner` interface.

```
@Override
    public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {

        String partitionKey = (String) key;

        if(Channel.DB.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(partitionKey) && ( KafkaTopic.TRANS.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(topic) || KafkaTopic.CONS.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(topic) )){
            return 1; // this is reserved for SERVICE X only
        }

        return 0; // here i want to produce messages on remaining partitions, how to return partition now?
    }
```

Problem:
1: how to return partition no. in such case
2: how other messages to be produced as round robin excluding partition for service X.

I am using Apache Kafka 9.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me -- here the idea is that when the key is not for the reserved partition, you remove that particular partition from the list of available partitions and round robin the remaining.

```
private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

public static final int SPECIAL_PARTITION_ID = 1;

@Override
public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {

    List<PartitionInfo> partitions = cluster.partitionsForTopic(topic);
    int numPartitions = partitions.size();

    String partitionKey = (String) key;

    if ("SPECIAL_CUSTOMER".equals(partitionKey)) {
        LOGGER.info("PARTITION= " + SPECIAL_PARTITION_ID);
        return SPECIAL_PARTITION_ID; //special partition reserved for MY_SPECIAL_CUSTOMER
    } else {
        int nextValue = counter.getAndIncrement();

        List<PartitionInfo> availablePartitions = new ArrayList<>(cluster.availablePartitionsForTopic(topic));

        if (availablePartitions.size() > 0) {

            PartitionInfo specialPartition = null;

            for (PartitionInfo partitionInfo : availablePartitions) {
                if (partitionInfo.partition() == SPECIAL_PARTITION_ID) {
                    specialPartition = partitionInfo;
                    break;
                }
            }

            availablePartitions.remove(specialPartition);

            int part = Utils.toPositive(nextValue) % availablePartitions.size();
            return availablePartitions.get(part).partition();
        } else {
            //optional -- depending upon your usecase
            while (true) {
                int p = Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % numPartitions;
                if(p != SPECIAL_PARTITION_ID) {
                    return p;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you could live with just making sure that one key always go to a reserved partition and other keys could be going to round-robin including the special partition, then you could easily achieve it by passing partitionId when key is for reserved partition and otherwise just not passing key at all, which could save you writing a custom partitioner.

Also, if you do not mind that reserved partition is the last partition and the rest goes to other partitions, there could be a simpler implementation (taken from the book "Kafka:The definitive guide")

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner;
import org.apache.kafka.common.Cluster;
import org.apache.kafka.common.PartitionInfo;
import org.apache.kafka.common.record.InvalidRecordException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils;

public class BananaPartitioner implements Partitioner {

    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {} 1

    public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes,
                           Object value, byte[] valueBytes,
                             Cluster cluster) {
        List<PartitionInfo> partitions =
          cluster.partitionsForTopic(topic);
        int numPartitions = partitions.size();

        if ((keyBytes == null) || (!(key instanceOf String))) 2
            throw new InvalidRecordException("We expect all messages
              to have customer name as key")

        if (((String) key).equals("Banana"))
            return numPartitions; // Banana will always go to last
                                     partition

        // Other records will get hashed to the rest of the
           partitions
        return (Math.abs(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % (numPartitions - 1))
    }

    public void close() {}
}
```